# Win10 doesn't run program unless it is in C: parition

Tags: windows, access-denied

I have wrote simple hello program:
when I execute it in E: partition it gives access denied message, while it works well on C: partition without any errors.
I have put the program in desktop and in C:/ drive and both worked.

My question is:
How can I execute programs from E:/ drive in win 10?

"E:/ is a logical drive and it's shared with arch-linux and another OS"
I was running win7 and it was okay, I even tried some programs which I compiled under win7 and they all worked in E:/ normally.
I am using this sublime' build for c program:

```
{
    "cmd":
    [ 
        "gcc", "-ggdb3", "-O0", "-std=c99", "-Wall", "-Werror", "$file",
        "-lm",
        "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "start","cmd", "/K" , "$file_base_name"
    ],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true
}
```

I am running win-10 with don't use developer feature.

Comment: what is `E:\` ? logical drive? subst/netuse mount?

Comment: It was 550GB and I wanted install another OS, so I made it 500 and the extra 50 is for the other OS. so it is a sub partition of the 550., but it was working well on win7.

Comment: you could try SysInternal tools. There's one tool which logs the system calls made when you're running a program (FileMon, ProcMon ? don't remember). Logs success and failures of all micro operations. Should help. Helped me a lot in the past.

Comment: OK. I will try that tomorrow as this took my long time to install win10 with my old programs. thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: 1) That's not about programming 2) The C tag is not about **partition** "C:".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the partition permissions:

Everyone group got a deny sign beside, so I just removed that group and checked full control for Eveyone and replaced all permissions(apply...OK).

Thanks Jean-François Fabre and all the others.